# Interfaces for WinForm UI-objects

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, interface

I want to implement several similar forms but can not simply subclass a baseform because the similarities are slightly too complex for this.
If it were classes which just contain logic, i would write several interfaces (or maybe even use the decorator pattern) to generate them by implementing some of those interfaces. However in my case i need to have specific controls on my forms if i implement one of these interfaces. Thus i would like to implement an interface in my viewmodel and 'force' any corresponding form to contain the needed controls.

While i can obviously implement an interface with a class that inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form, this does not seem straightforward for what i would like to do (especially since the form itself should not contain any logic). Is there a "proper" way to verify that my forms contain the expected controls when i bind them to a viewmodel which implements specific interfaces?

In case the question was not clear enough, here an **example**:

I got 10 Forms containing a TabControl with 4 Tabs total. 3 Tabs are identical for all forms. A 4th tab needs to contain a button for some of my forms and a textbox for the rest. I would like to implement an Interface IButtonTab or ITextboxTab in my Viewmodel to provide the needed Properties.
How do I ensure that the Forms actually contain the expected controls when i implement these interfaces? (I want to be able to implement both interfaces later on if needed and thus show both tabs in my TabControl.)

(I am aware that in this case i could add both, a textbox and a button tab to my TabControl and remove any tabs which are not needed. This does not seem viable for more complex situations though.)

Comment: Thinking about it, the MVP pattern would probably be more useful here. Sticking to the example, my presenter would implement ITextboxTab and contain a private membervariable of type ITextboxView. I just need a way to "force" any object which implements ITextboxView to contain specific controls (a tab with a textbox in this case.)